# What's the difference between "static" and "static inline" function?

Tags: c, inline

IMO both make the function to have a scope of the translation unit only.

What's the difference between "static" and "static inline" function?

Why should `inline` be put in a header file, not in `.c` file?

Comment: [Is "inline" without "static" or "extern" ever useful in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6312597) shows the actual syntax necessary in the `.h` and the `extern inline` declaration in exactly one `.c` to make a working C program with a non-static `inline` function defined in a header and thus able to actually inline.  [In C, should inline functions in headers be externed in the .c file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62475308) is also about that.

Answer (score 150):

By default, an inline definition is only valid in the current translation unit.

If the storage class is `extern`, the identifier has external linkage and the inline definition also provides the external definition.

If the storage class is `static`, the identifier has internal linkage and the inline definition is invisible in other translation units.

If the storage class is unspecified, the inline definition is only visible in the current translation unit, but the identifier still has external linkage and an external definition must be provided in a different translation unit. The compiler is free to use either the inline or the external definition if the function is called within the current translation unit.

As the compiler is free to inline (and to not inline) any function whose definition is visible in the current translation unit (and, thanks to link-time optimizations, even in different translation units, though the C standard doesn't really account for that), for most practical purposes, there's no difference between `static` and `static inline` function definitions.

The `inline` specifier (like the `register` storage class) is only a compiler hint, and the compiler is free to completely ignore it. Standards-compliant non-optimizing compilers only have to honor their side-effects, and optimizing compilers will do these optimizations with or without explicit hints.

`inline` and `register` are not useless, though, as they instruct the compiler to throw errors when the programmer writes code that would make the optimizations impossible: An external `inline` definition can't reference identifiers with internal linkage (as these would be unavailable in a different translation unit) or define modifiable local variables with static storage duration (as these wouldn't share state accross translation units), and you can't take addresses of `register`-qualified variables.

Personally, I use the convention to mark `static` function definitions within headers also `inline`, as the main reason for putting function definitions in header files is to make them inlinable.

In general, I only use `static inline` function and `static const` object definitions in addition to `extern` declarations within headers.

I've never written an `inline` function with a storage class different from `static`.

Comment: I read your entire answer and I still don't get the semantic difference between `static` and `static inline`. Both of them make the definition invisible to other translation units. So what would be a sensible reason to write `static inline` instead of `static`?

Comment: +1 for the hugely insightful reminder that they are not useless, because they instruct the compiler to treat impossibility to do those optimizations as an error!

Comment: @user541686 The biggest and most important semantic difference is that `static inline` expresses your intent/approval for it to be inlined, whereas `static` does not. To be clear about definitions, "semantics" is basically a fancy word for "meaning", and so that is the most essential semantic difference right there. Because source code is first and foremost about describing what you intend for the code to do. And if you proactively intend for inlining to happen, you should say so, and `inline` is the most "native" way to say so in the language of C.

Comment: @user541686 That said, I think there is an important thinking difference between "I intend for this to be inlined" and "I intend to empower the compiler (or the person invoking the compiler) to decide whether or not inlining is optimal in this case". Personally, I would only use `static inline` when I explicitly thought it was *better* for the function to be inlined, and `static` in any other situation. And I only very, very rarely actually want to assert that it is better for something to be inlined - because that seems very situational (very implementation-dependent and usecase-dependent).

Comment: @mtraceur, I think user541686 was wanting to know the practical/compiler meaning, not the programmer intent.  If intent was the only deciding factor then couldn't I just `#define I_INTEND_FOR_THIS_TO_BE_INLINED` to be a nop, and place it after `static`? But from the answer itself, I gathered that the compiler meaning is: "emit an error if this `extern inline` function tries to use a `static` variable." But this isn't the case with a `static inline` function, so I also don't understand the difference between `static inline` and `static INLINE_INTENT` where `INLINE_INTENT` is an empty `#define`.

Comment: @jdk1-0 Intent is ideally communicated to _both_ humans _and_ software. Humans first and foremost, but the compiler and other tools can do a better job at optimizing or detecting problems if you can tell them your intent. So in the intent perspective, the difference between `static inline` and `static INLINE_INTENT` is that one of them also reveals your intent to compilers and other software (because we standardized on that as _the_ way to express that specific intent).

Comment: Clang llvm uses a different threshold for inline specified functions: https://godbolt.org/z/rar9adfbv
I dare say clang trunk is a "modern compiler"

Comment: "The inline specifier (like the register storage class) is only a compiler hint, and the compiler is free to completely ignore it."
I'm sorry but this is plain wrong.
The inline specifier might be a optimization hint for the compiler, depending on the compiler.
But in any case, the inline specifier changes the linkage!!
If you don't make non-template header-defined functions inline, you'll get duplicated symbols if the header is included in multiple translation units!
Template functions are implicitely inline.

Answer (score 124):

`inline` instructs the compiler to **attempt to** embed the function content into the calling code instead of executing an actual call.

For small functions that are called frequently that can make a big performance difference.

However, this is only a "hint", and the compiler may ignore it, and most compilers will try to "inline" even when the keyword is not used, as part of the optimizations, where its possible.

for example:

```
static int Inc(int i) {return i+1};
.... // some code
int i;
.... // some more code
for (i=0; i<999999; i = Inc(i)) {/*do something here*/};
```

This tight loop will perform a function call on each iteration, and the function content is actually significantly less than the code the compiler needs to put to perform the call. `inline` will essentially instruct the compiler to convert the code above into an equivalent of:

```
 int i;
 ....
 for (i=0; i<999999; i = i+1) { /* do something here */};
```

Skipping the actual function call and return

Obviously this is an example to show the point, not a real piece of code.

`static` refers to the scope. In C it means that the function/variable can only be used within the same translation unit.

Comment: Apart from the embedding feature,it's the same as `static`,right?

Comment: It's also important to note that code declared as inline belongs in the header, where as normal (non-template) source code cannot go in headers without causing multiple redefinition errors. So even when declaring something inline, even if the compiler chooses not to inline it, there is still a standard-mandated multiple-redefinition avoiding behavior that kicks in.

Comment: @VoidStar Actually `static` (with or without `inline`) can be in header perfectly well, see no reason why not. Templates is for C++, this question is about C.

Comment: @littleadv: the main reason for putting function definitions in header files is to make them inlinable, so marking them explicitly `inline` is good style, imo

Comment: Have you actually tried compiling your example into assembly? At least when I tried it with GCC 4.9, with no `-O` flag, or if `-O0` is specified, the function call is still there. If you compile it with `-O1` or above, now it is actually inlined, but even not specifying `inline` still inlines it, so there is no difference between `static` and `static inline`.

Comment: Actually `inline` doesn't _instruct_ the compiler to do any attempts at inlining. It merely lets the programmer to include function body in multiple translation units without ODR violation. A side effect of this is that it's makes it possible for the compiler, when it _would_ inline the function, to actually do this.

Comment: @Ruslan No, `static` already does all that, and predates `inline`. `inline` was added after, as a way to explicitly suggest that the intended or optimal thing is for the function to be inlined.

Comment: @Ruslan You are right that it is not *instructing* the compiler to attempt inlining. It is merely *suggesting* to the compiler to do so. But everything else you said after that was already done by `static` before `inline` was added to the language.

Comment: @mtraceur `inline` non-`static` lets the compiler make the function accessible from other translation units instead of creating it (as it would with `static`) in every translation unit even in cases where the function is never inlined. All the cases `static`, `inline` and `static inline` are distinct in their semantics.

Comment: @Ruslan Okay, I see what you mean now. But to me your original comment does not seem to clearly draw that distinction. When I read that earlier comment, all I get out of it is: 1. `inline` allows including the definition of the function in multiple translation units without an ODR violation (which `static` also does), and 2. `inline` as a side-effect empowers the compiler to inline the function (which `static` also does). The distinction between whether or not there is a copy in each translation unit does not seem to be mentioned, so I wasn't rejecting that.

Comment: @Ruslan Also, a `static` function which is never used in a translation unit can simply be omitted entirely by the compiler when generating the code for that translation unit, and if all uses of a `static` function are inlined by a compiler, it is similarly free to not generate an independent copy. It seems your original comment was written with non-`static` functions in mind, and I totally agree with it if so, because yeah, `inline` allows bodies of `extern` functions to be included in multiple translation without violating the ODR, and this in turn empowers the compiler to inline them.

Comment: @mtraceur you seem to be trying to read into my two-year-old comment as if it were an answer. It isn't, so it can't be edited, thus I don't think it's useful to try to spend such an effort to critique it.

Comment: @Ruslan it was useful to me, because it helped me actually understand what you meant and to discover an angle of thinking from which the wording you used in it would have been naturally the wording I might have used too. Your initial comment brought up a good point that elaborates on the answer, but in a wording that meant something else to me - I think these follow-up comments will help clarify that point for other readers like myself.

Answer (score 33):

From my experience with GCC I know that `static` and `static inline` differs in a way how compiler issue warnings about unused functions. More precisely when you declare `static` function and it isn't used in current translation unit then compiler produce warning about unused function, but you can inhibit that warning with changing it to `static inline`.

Thus I tend to think that `static` should be used in translation units and benefit from extra check compiler does to find unused functions. And `static inline` should be used in header files to provide functions that can be in-lined (due to absence of external linkage) without issuing warnings.

Unfortunately I cannot find any evidence for that logic. Even from GCC documentation I wasn't able to conclude that `inline` inhibits unused function warnings. I'd appreciate if someone will share links to description of that.

Comment: Mmm, still got `warning: unused function 'function' [clang-diagnostic-unused-function]` for a `static inline` function when building with`clang-tidy` (v8.0.1), which is used in another translation unit. But definitely, this is one of the best explanations and reason for combining `static` & `inline`!

Comment: @DrumM, but ony was referring to gcc.  But you're right, this is probably the best explanation so far.

Answer (score 8):

In C, `static` means the function or variable you define can be only used in this file(i.e. the compile unit)

So, `static inline` means the inline function which can be used in this file only.

**EDIT:**

*The compile unit* should be *The Translation Unit*

Comment: Or in fancy words: it has internal linkage.

Comment: @AlokSave: Is there a difference between _compilation unit_ and _translation unit_? If so, which is more appropriate in the context of the C++ language?

Comment: I believe `the compile unit` is something I wrote in error, there is no such thing, the actual terminology is `translation unit`

Comment: Your answer is not complete because it's mostly used in header files, accross translation units.

Answer (score 8):

One difference that's not at the language level but the popular implementation level: certain versions of gcc will remove unreferenced `static inline` functions from output by default, but will keep plain `static` functions even if unreferenced. I'm not sure which versions this applies to, but from a practical standpoint it means it may be a good idea to always use `inline` for `static` functions in headers.

Comment: What about using `inline` in definition? Do you also imply not using it for `extern` functions?

Comment: Is this still true with recent version of GCC? Your answer would be a lot more interesting if you an example and listed the which version of GCC do it.

Comment: @Zboson: I don't have that information readily available and don't have time to setup and test lots of gcc versions at the moment, but I agree it would be useful information to have. You could probably find when gcc first started optimizing out unused static functions/objects by looking at the history of `attribute((used))` and its use to allow asm to reference otherwise-unreferenced `static` functions and data.

Comment: major versions of gcc from 4.1 all the way to 11.1 will remove unused `static` and unused `static inline` functions over at godbolt.org.  And they all warn about unused for `static` functions, but none warn for unused `static inline`.  Also, unspecified storage class functions will remain if unused, without warning (even with optimizations).  But I don't know how to test with headers on that site.  (And I would get linker errors on anything above gcc 4.9.x when trying to compile with just `inline`.)

Answer (score 4):

In C++, [one important effect of `inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) (that is not mentioned in the other answers yet, I think) is that it prevents linker errors when multiple definitions of the function are found.

Consider a function that is defined in a header file to allow it to be inlined into the source files that include the header. If the compiler decides to *not* inline (all calls to) this function, the function definition will be included into every object file that references it (i.e. does not inline all calls).

This might cause multiple definitions of the functions to read the linker (though not always, since it depends on the inlining decisions made by the compiler). Without the `inline` keyword, this produces a linker error, but the `inline` keyword tells the linker to just pick one definition and discard the rest (which are expected to be equal, but this is not checked).

The `static` keyword, on the other hand, ensures that *if* a function is included in the object file, it will be private to that object file. If multiple object files contain the same function, they will coexist and all calls to the function will use their "own" version. This means that more memory is taken up. In practice, I believe this means that using `static` for functions defined in header files is not a good idea, better to just use `inline`.

In practice, this also means that `static` functions cannot produce linker errors, so the effect of `inline` above is not really useful for `static` functions. However, as suggested by [ony in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37864405/740048), adding `inline` might be helpful to prevent warnings for unused functions.

Note that the above is true for C++. In C, `inline` [works a bit different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/inline), and you have to explicitly put an `extern` declaration in a single source file to have the inline function emitted into that object file so it is available for any non-inlined uses. In other words, `inline` means that a function is not emitted into any source file, even when not all calls are inlined, unless it is also specified as `extern`, and then it *is* emitted (even if all local calls are inlined). I'm not sure how that interacts with `static`, though.

Answer (score 0):

An **inline** definition is not **external**ly linked.

```c
// average.h
#ifndef AVERAGE_H
#define AVERAGE_H
inline double average(double a, double b);
#endif
```

Attempting to call an **inline** function with the definition above from another
module **after** it has been preprocessed or linked to a c file will result in an error.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. make it a **static inline** function defintion.
   Example:

```c
// average.h
#ifndef AVERAGE_H
#define AVERAGE_H
static inline double average(double a, double b);
#endif
```

2. include the defintion from the c file and make it **external**.
   Example:

```c
#include "average.h"
extern double average(double a ,double b){ 
  return (a + b) / 2;
}
```

Comment: You can provide an `inline` definition in the header, otherwise you're defeating the purpose of declaring it `inline`.  You do still need to instantiate an `extern inline` copy of the function in one compilation unit.