# In kernel module can I call static inline function defined in another header file of the kernel source?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I will try to make the question clear. I am developing a loadable kernel module and just wondering whether I can call a static inline function defined in another header file of the Linux kernel source.
I understand that the static keyword makes the function restricted within the scope of the compilation unit(i.e. a C file). But if I include the header file where the static inline function is defined, can I use it in my module?

Comment: What else would you do with a function (static inline or not) than to call it? Did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Whether I can call a static inline function defined in another header file of the Linux kernel source??***

Yes. Possible. **kmalloc()** is an example for it. This function is defined in **include/linux/slab.h** as a `static inline`  function. Suggest to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428433/small-functions-defined-in-header-files-inline-or-static) post which explains why static inline is used in header files.

References
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/slab.h#L452
[What's the difference between "static" and "static inline" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762731/whats-the-difference-between-static-and-static-inline-function?lq=1)