# Should the static and inline functions be defined in .h file?

Tags: c

When I write software in C, should I put `static` and `inline` functions in the `.h` or in the `.c` file?

Comment: Their declaration or definition ?

Comment: You should not put `static` functions in a `.h` file, because if you need to, then the function should not be static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not put the declaration nor definition of a `static` function (or variable) in a `.h` file.  That defeats the points of `static` - keeping functions/variables local.

`inline` is another matter - it depends on the scope meant for the function.  An `inline` function in a `.h` is meant for global usage and scope.  An `inline` function in a `.c` is meant for local usage only.  This is much the same strategy as would be used for a `#define`

`inline` functions can be `extern`, `static` or unspecified.  [@Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7767858/2410359) well explains `inline` scope issues.

Comment: True, except you usually want your inline functions static. At least I rarely bother to instantiate external inline definitions.

Comment: A good read about the why and how of inline and static functions in C, is [**Inline Functions In C**](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming multiple C source files include the .h file, then inline functions in the .h file are ok, but I'm not sure why you'd want a static function in a .h file, to end up being duplicated, once for each C source file. The compiler may be smart enough to not generate code for static functions that are not called within a C source file.