# Is it ok to define static inline function with same name in different files?

Tags: c

For example, `a.h`

```
static inline void asdf(int a) {}
```

`b.h`

```
static inline void asdf(int a) {}
```

is this ok? will there be any conflicts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "static" and "static inline" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762731/whats-the-difference-between-static-and-static-inline-function)

Comment: Why not define it in a *single* header file that you include where the function is needed? At least you would avoid conflicts if you some day need to include both `a.h` and `b.h`.

Comment: There isn't any conflict unless both a.h and b.h are included in one cpp file. But it is a bad practice to implement static functions in header file.

Comment: `static` is `static`,  the func might be inlined or no, that's another problem.

Comment: @iamnoten: It is bad practice to implement `static` non-`inline` functions in a header.  It is perfectly reasonable to implement `static inline` functions in a header — indeed, as long as the function is (small enough and simple enough to be) inlined, it is perfectly sensible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only be ok if no single source ever include both headers. If all  .c files either include only a.h or only b.h or none, then all will be fine.

If both header were included in same source, you would get an error for redefinition of asdf.

An acceptable example would be if none of the .c files include directly a.h or b.h but only a c.h file containing:

```
#ifdef A_TYPE
#include a.h
#else
#include b.h
#endif
```

because the choice of the implementation would rely on a compile time constant

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes, it's ok. static functions are only visible in the same compilation unit.

Practically, no, it's not ok. It makes your code hard to read and if I had to maintain your code later I'd hate you for it. Either because the functions do different things or because they diverge over time because someone fixed a bug in one of them and forgot the other.

Comment: What happens if I include both headers in the same c file?

Comment: @NO - You'll have two conflicting definitions in one translation unit. Neither static nor inline will help with that. It's a hard error.

Comment: I agree. That's why it might be problematic even technically

Answer (score 1):

A static inline function does not need a declaration to be included in the header file.

You can have the declaration in the .c file where it is used.

e.g. `a.c`

```
static inline void asdf(int a);

....
static inline void asdf(int a)
{
   ....
}
```

In such a case the two different functions can be used in two files.