# Precedence of -D MACRO and #define MACRO 5

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

Hello everybody I'm programming on Visual C++ 6.0 IDE my problem is: I tried to define macros from the command line at first I did this: `project->settings` c++ command definitions and i entered this macro: `-DHELLO="HELLO!`" when I use it from my source code I entered:

```
#ifdef HELLO
HELLO;
#endif
```

Until this everything is OK.

But my problem is with macros those takes arguments, so how I set a macro with arguments and the second question is how to expand it from source code?

Any help is really appreciated. I spent a lot of time googling and searching, reading ebooks but this didn't help.

Comment: Your title mentions precedence while your body has nothing to do with precedence. You need to be a bit more in focus on things.

Comment: I didn't understand. could you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible...

If you take a look at the Microsoft documentation, the `/D` option is constructed like :

```
/Dname[= | # [{string | number}] ]
```

As it seems to be impossible to add parantheses, I don't it is possible to create *function-like* macro with this command line option...

---

NB: It's weird that I tried on Visual Studio, my intellisense see it as *function-like* macro, so no error visible in the code (no red line under it), but when it's time to compile I get :

```
error C3861: 'MACRO_TEST': identifier not found
```

With a definition of type :

```
/D"MACRO_TEST( tst )= tst" // or -D"MACRO_TEST( tst )= tst"
```

Comment: Thnk you very much for your help that enlightened me after being so tired after a long research. so you mean it is not possible to define a function-like macro from command line?. what you said about the macro definition from preprocessor definitions seems to me completely correct

Comment: @ProDev7 After the tests I did and the searches on the internet, I am pretty sure that it is not possible for now with any version of Visual Studio. Maybe you should define your *function-like* MACRO inside a Header file that you include only inside the projects you want it to be included ?

Comment: Thank you too much Pierre. in fact I was hopeless to find a convincing reply even on MSDN. until I got you reoly.

Comment: But Pierre what is the point to define a function-like macro in a header file?

Comment: @ProDev7 You have a great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616802/when-to-use-function-like-macros-in-c). After, the fact that the macro is defined inside your command line or inside an header file is of your taste I think. Personally I prefer inside the Header because it is more obvious for developers (I think, but it is only my opinion here :) )

Comment: ok Pierre. I'm new hewre could you show me how to validate the answer?

Comment: @ProDev7 Also, if you search for *function-like macro* around the web, you will see that everyone use `#define` in a header instead of the command line argument ;)

Comment: ok. thank you. and now I got it that it is not possible to define function-like macros on command line.

Comment: Pierre I want to validate your answers but I don't see any checkbox. could you explain more?

Comment: Pierre I finally found the arrows you told me about. but when I click on it it says to me that "Vote up requires 15 reputations"

Comment: if i got enough reputations I promise you to vote up on all your answers.

Comment: Pierre coud you answer this question:

Comment: Hello everybody I am still confused with defining degug macros;I want some explanation why do we use #define DEBUG, #define NDEBUG #define _DEBUG could you explain it to me showing the point in using them?
I hear we use them to remove some debugging code whne compilation??
als if use in program: #define _DEBUG I got warning telling me Macro _DEBUG redifibition.
what about turning on and off Debug?????
I do recognize your help and making it cleared up to me.

Comment: @ProDev7 `#define DEBUG` and `#define _DEBUG` are defined by Visual Studio when you are compiling in debug mode. It permits to you to have some code only in debug (for debugging purpose). Look : http://ideone.com/NS0FXD.

Comment: I paid a visit to the link and I found the example. but I still don't know the real reason people use #define DEBUG or _DEBUG. please explain more in details as you did a lot of efforts for me with the command line macros. thank you for your time and effort